# Sliding window sample from a data frame

Tags: r

Let's suppose I have a data frame of 20 rows(cols are not imp here) 
I want to generate a set of sequential sample data of 5 rows each in the order of:

1st to 5th observations...
2nd to 6th observations....
3rd to 7th observations & so on till...
16th to 20th.

Essentially it would be (n+1)-5 separate datasets.

I guess the split function can be used but not very sure about defining the "f" argument in the function.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that your dataset consists of the first 20 rows of `iris`:

```
df<-iris[1:20,]
```

Then you can try:

```
nr <- nrow(df)
windowSize <- 5
lapply(seq_len(nr-windowSize+1), function(i) df[i:(i+windowSize-1),])
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks a lot.